# I cant get JQuery to function? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css

To whom it may concern,

I am trying to make a list navigation menu as in the first tab in:
http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx

When I click on each letter it doesnt display the number of options available as in the demo. Also my list is constantly displaying not hidden until clicked on as in the the demo.

Can you help me tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.listnav.pack-2.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="listnav.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset-min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

<script> 
$('#demoOne').listnav();
</script> 
</head>

<body>

<h4>Testing jqList:</h4>
<div id="demoOne-nav" class="listNav">
    <div class="ln-letters">    

        <a class="all" href="#">ALL </a>
        <a class="_" href="#">0-9 </a> 
        <a class="a" href="#">A </a>
        <a class="b" href="#">B </a>
        <a class="c" href="#">C </a>
        <a class="d" href="#">D </a>
        <a class="e" href="#">E </a>
        <a class="f" href="#">F </a>
        <a class="g" href="#">G </a>
        <a class="h" href="#">H </a>
        <a class="i" href="#">I </a>
        <a class="j" href="#">J </a>
        <a class="k" href="#">K </a>
        <a class="l" href="#">L </a>
        <a class="m" href="#">M </a>
        <a class="n" href="#">N </a>
        <a class="o" href="#">O </a>
        <a class="p" href="#">P </a>
        <a class="q" href="#">Q </a>
        <a class="r" href="#">R </a>
        <a class="s" href="#">S </a>
        <a class="u" href="#">U </a>
        <a class="v" href="#">V </a>
        <a class="w" href="#">W </a>
        <a class="x" href="#">X </a>
        <a class="y ln-selected" href="#">Y </a>
        <a class="z ln-disabled ln-last" href="#">Z </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ln-letter-count" style="top: 293px; left: 102px; width: 21px; position: absolute; display: none;" >13 </div>
</div>

<ul id="demoOne" class="demo">

<li class="ln-_" style= "display: none;"> <a href="#"> 411 Services </a> <li>
<li class="ln-a;"> <a href="#"> Adams </a> <li>
<li class="ln-z;"> <a href="#"> fake </a> <li>

</ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS file is:

```
.listNav { margin:0 0 10px; }
.ln-letters { overflow:hidden; }
.ln-letters a { font-size:0.9em; display:block; float:left; padding:2px 6px; border:1px solid silver; border-right:none; text-decoration:none; }
.ln-letters a.ln-last { border-right:1px solid silver; }
.ln-letters a:hover,
.ln-letters a.ln-selected { background-color:#eaeaea; }
.ln-letters a.ln-disabled { color:#ccc; }
.ln-letter-count { text-align:center; font-size:0.8em; line-height:1; margin-bottom:3px; color:#336699; }
```

AND THE JS FILE IS:

```
/*
*
* jQuery listnav plugin
* Copyright (c) 2009 iHwy, Inc.
* Author: Jack Killpatrick
*
* Version 2.1 (08/09/2009)
* Requires jQuery 1.3.2, jquery 1.2.6 or jquery 1.2.x plus the jquery dimensions plugin
*
* Visit http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx for more information.
*
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
*/

(function($) {
    $.fn.listnav = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.listnav.defaults, options);
        var letters = ['_', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-'];
        var firstClick = false;
        opts.prefixes = $.map(opts.prefixes, function(n) { return n.toLowerCase(); });

        return this.each(function() {
            var $wrapper, list, $list, $letters, $letterCount, id;
            id = this.id;
            $wrapper = $('#' + id + '-nav'); // user must abide by the convention: <ul id="myList"> for list and <div id="myList-nav"> for nav wrapper
            $list = $(this);

            var counts = {}, allCount = 0, isAll = true, numCount = 0, prevLetter = '';

            function init() {
                $wrapper.append(createLettersHtml());

                $letters = $('.ln-letters', $wrapper).slice(0, 1); // will always be a single item
                if (opts.showCounts) $letterCount = $('.ln-letter-count', $wrapper).slice(0, 1); // will always be a single item

                addClasses();
                addNoMatchLI();
                if (opts.flagDisabled) addDisabledClass();
                bindHandlers();

                if (!opts.includeAll) $list.show(); // show the list in case the recommendation for includeAll=false was taken

                // remove nav items we don't need
                //
                if (!opts.includeAll) $('.all', $letters).remove();
                if (!opts.includeNums) $('._', $letters).remove();
                if (!opts.includeOther) $('.-', $letters).remove();

                $(':last', $letters).addClass('ln-last'); // allows for styling a case where last item needs right border set (because items before that only have top, left and bottom so that border between items isn't doubled)

                if ($.cookie && (opts.cookieName != null)) {
                    var cookieLetter = $.cookie(opts.cookieName);
                    if (cookieLetter != null) opts.initLetter = cookieLetter;
                }

                // decide what to show first
                //
                if (opts.initLetter != '') {
                    firstClick = true;
                    $('.' + opts.initLetter.toLowerCase(), $letters).slice(0, 1).click(); // click the initLetter if there was one
                }
                else {
                    if (opts.includeAll) $('.all', $letters).addClass('ln-selected'); // showing all: we don't need to click this: the whole list is already loaded
                    else { // ALL link is hidden, click the first letter that will display LI's
                        for (var i = ((opts.includeNums) ? 0 : 1); i < letters.length; i++) {
                            if (counts[letters[i]] > 0) {
                                firstClick = true;
                                $('.' + letters[i], $letters).slice(0, 1).click();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // positions the letter count div above the letter links (so we only have to do it once: after this we just change it's left position via mouseover)
            //
            function setLetterCountTop() {
                $letterCount.css({ top: $('.a', $letters).slice(0, 1).offset({ margin: false, border: true }).top - $letterCount.outerHeight({ margin: true }) }); // note: don't set top based on '.all': it might not be visible
            }

            // adds a class to each LI that has text content inside of it (ie, inside an <a>, a <div>, nested DOM nodes, etc)
            //
            function addClasses() {
                var str, firstChar, firstWord, spl, $this, hasPrefixes = (opts.prefixes.length > 0);
                $($list).children().each(function() {
                    $this = $(this), firstChar = '', str = $.trim($this.text()).toLowerCase();
                    if (str != '') {
                        if (hasPrefixes) {
                            spl = str.split(' ');
                            if ((spl.length > 1) && ($.inArray(spl[0], opts.prefixes) > -1)) {
                                firstChar = spl[1].charAt(0);
                                addLetterClass(firstChar, $this, true);
                            }
                        }
                        firstChar = str.charAt(0);
                        addLetterClass(firstChar, $this);
                    }
                });
            }

            function addLetterClass(firstChar, $el, isPrefix) {
                if (/\W/.test(firstChar)) firstChar = '-'; // not A-Z, a-z or 0-9, so considered "other"
                if (!isNaN(firstChar)) firstChar = '_'; // use '_' if the first char is a number
                $el.addClass('ln-' + firstChar);

                if (counts[firstChar] == undefined) counts[firstChar] = 0;
                counts[firstChar]++;
                if (!isPrefix) allCount++;
            }

            function addDisabledClass() {
                for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                    if (counts[letters[i]] == undefined) $('.' + letters[i], $letters).addClass('ln-disabled');
                }
            }

            function addNoMatchLI() {
                $list.append('<li class="ln-no-match" style="display:none">' + opts.noMatchText + '</li>');
            }

            function getLetterCount(el) {
                if ($(el).hasClass('all')) return allCount;
                else {
                    var count = counts[$(el).attr('class').split(' ')[0]];
                    return (count != undefined) ? count : 0; // some letters may not have a count in the hash
                }
            }

            function bindHandlers() {

                // sets the top position of the count div in case something above it on the page has resized
                //
                if (opts.showCounts) {
                    $wrapper.mouseover(function() {
                        setLetterCountTop();
                    });
                }

                // mouseover for each letter: shows the count above the letter
                //
                if (opts.showCounts) {
                    $('a', $letters).mouseover(function() {
                        var left = $(this).position().left;
                        var width = ($(this).outerWidth({ margin: true }) - 1) + 'px'; // the -1 is to tweak the width a bit due to a seeming inaccuracy in jquery ui/dimensions outerWidth (same result in FF2 and IE6/7)
                        var count = getLetterCount(this);
                        $letterCount.css({ left: left, width: width }).text(count).show(); // set left position and width of letter count, set count text and show it
                    });

                    // mouseout for each letter: hide the count
                    //
                    $('a', $letters).mouseout(function() {
                        $letterCount.hide();
                    });
                }

                // click handler for letters: shows/hides relevant LI's
                //
                $('a', $letters).click(function() {
                    $('a.ln-selected', $letters).removeClass('ln-selected');

                    var letter = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

                    if (letter == 'all') {
                        $list.children().show();
                        $list.children('.ln-no-match').hide();
                        isAll = true;
                    } else {
                        if (isAll) {
                            $list.children().hide();
                            isAll = false;
                        } else if (prevLetter != '') $list.children('.ln-' + prevLetter).hide();

                        var count = getLetterCount(this);
                        if (count > 0) {
                            $list.children('.ln-no-match').hide(); // in case it's showing
                            $list.children('.ln-' + letter).show();
                        }
                        else $list.children('.ln-no-match').show();

                        prevLetter = letter;
                    }

                    if ($.cookie && (opts.cookieName != null)) $.cookie(opts.cookieName, letter);


                    $(this).addClass('ln-selected');
                    $(this).blur();
                    if (!firstClick && (opts.onClick != null)) opts.onClick(letter);
                    else firstClick = false;
                    return false;
                });
            }

            // creates the HTML for the letter links
            //  
            function createLettersHtml() {
                var html = [];
                for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
                    if (html.length == 0) html.push('<a class="all" href="#">ALL</a><a class="_" href="#">0-9</a>');
                    html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">' + ((letters[i] == '-') ? '...' : letters[i].toUpperCase()) + '</a>');
                }
                return '<div class="ln-letters">' + html.join('') + '</div>' + ((opts.showCounts) ? '<div class="ln-letter-count" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:20px;">0</div>' : ''); // the styling for ln-letter-count is to give us a starting point for the element, which will be repositioned when made visible (ie, should not need to be styled by the user)
            }

            init();
        });
    };

    $.fn.listnav.defaults = {
        initLetter: '',
        includeAll: true,
        incudeOther: false,
        includeNums: true,
        flagDisabled: true,
        noMatchText: 'No matching entries',
        showCounts: true,
        cookieName: null,
        onClick: null,
        prefixes: []
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you try using the uncompressed or minified version of the plugin instead of the packed version. Packing has cause all kinds of issues in the past. Are you getting any js errors on your error console? Do other jquery functions work?

Comment: I haven't actually tried running your code, but the culprit is usually that you try to access an element before it is loaded in the DOM. Try moving the `<script>$('#demoOne').listnav();</script>` to the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Also you need to wrap `$('#demoOne').listnav();` like `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#demoOne').listnav(); });` or the shorthand `$(function(){ $('#demoOne').listnav(); });`

Comment: Please don't dump all your code on us and say "where is the problem?" Narrow it down to a minimal code example that still has the problem or, if that's absolutely impossible, post code dumps that size in a pastebin. A) It shows you put at least a minimal amount of effort into solving the problem, and B) it makes it easier for us to quickly see the problem, as opposed to having to wade through massive amounts of code unrelated to your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only run the javascript when it's necessary. i.e. when the page has done loading all it's content

try

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demoOne').listnav();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Cheers Pieter. Very helpful advice

Answer (score 1):

The element `demoOne` does not exist at the time you execute the script, so it fails. You must execute the script after the element is part of the DOM. One way you can do this is by executing it directly after your `demoOne` element, like this:

```
<ul id="demoOne" class="demo">
    <li class="ln-_" style= "display: none;"> <a href="#"> 411 Services </a> <li>
    <li class="ln-a;"> <a href="#"> Adams </a> <li>
    <li class="ln-z;"> <a href="#"> fake </a> <li>
</ul>
<script> 
  $('#demoOne').listnav();
</script>
```

It's recommended, though, to execute these types of things when the DOM is "ready". [Pieter's answer show you how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352444/18265).